# How to apply filters on nested object array

Tags: html, angularjs

Hello guys I'm new to angularjs.I'm trying to apply filter on the following thing.But what happening is it is not iterating all list values with ng-repeat followed by some filters.It only iterating  jobseekerId 1,2 only but not 3.Where as if I'm removing the filter means it iterating all list values(1,2,3).
What is the problem with my code .Please give some suggestion.

## This is my data

```
 [ {
          "jobSeekerId" : 1,
          "firstName" : "vijay",
          "middleName" : null,
          "lastName" : "sury",
          "jobSeekerProfTitle" : "Having 2.2yerars of experience in the field java development with spring and hibernate",
          "profileUpdateDate" : "05 May 2014",
          "currentState" : "ap",
          "profilePath" : "E:/opt/jsimages/recru-profile.jpg",
          "currentCity" : "hyd",
          "salary" : "20000",
          "salaryType" : "per month",
          "jobSeekerSkillVo" : [ {
            "skill" : "js"
          }, {
            "skill" : "java"
          }, {
            "skill" : "uuu"
          } ],
          "academicInfoVo" : [ {
            "academicInfoId" : 1,
            "courseName" : "btech",
            "universityName" : "intuk",
            "academicEndYear" : 2014,
            "gpa" : 10.0
          } ],
          "city" : [ "hyd", "ts" ],
          "totalExperience" : "48",
          "viewCount" : "2",
          "downloadCount" : "0",
          "viewStatus" : "alive"
        }, {
          "jobSeekerId" : 2,
          "firstName" : "raj",
          "middleName" : null,
          "lastName" : "sury",
          "jobSeekerProfTitle" : null,
          "profileUpdateDate" : null,
          "currentState" : null,
          "profilePath" : null,
          "currentCity" : null,
          "salary" : null,
          "salaryType" : null,
          "jobSeekerSkillVo" : [ {
            "skill" : "uuu"
          }, {
            "skill" : "java"
          } ],
          "academicInfoVo" : [ {
            "academicInfoId" : 2,
            "courseName" : "btech",
            "universityName" : "intuk",
            "academicEndYear" : 2014,
            "gpa" : 8.0
          } ],
          "city" : [ ],
          "totalExperience" : "14",
          "viewCount" : "1",
          "downloadCount" : "0",
          "viewStatus" : "alive"
        }, {
          "jobSeekerId" : 3,
          "firstName" : "vj",
          "middleName" : null,
          "lastName" : "gg",
          "jobSeekerProfTitle" : null,
          "profileUpdateDate" : null,
          "currentState" : null,
          "profilePath" : null,
          "currentCity" : null,
          "salary" : "20000",
          "salaryType" : "per month",
          "jobSeekerSkillVo" : [ ],
          "academicInfoVo" : [ ],
          "city" : [ ],
          "totalExperience" : "0",
          "viewCount" : "1",
          "downloadCount" : "0",
          "viewStatus" : "alive"
        } ]
```

======================
This is my filter

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="candidateListApp" ng-controller="candidateListController">
<span ng-cloak  ng-repeat="jsList in jobSeekerList|filter:{jobSeekerSkillVo:
                                       {skill:drpSkill},})}}">                              
    <a ng-href="#">                                             
            {{jsList.firstName}}&nbsp;{{jsList.lastName}}
     </a>
</span>
<span ng-if="jsList.jobSeekerSkillVo.length != 0">
    <span ng-repeat="skills in jsList.jobSeekerSkillVo">
            {{skills.skill}}
            {{$last?'':','}}
    </span>
</span>
</div>
<script>
var app=angular.module("candidateListApp",[]);
    app.controller("candidateListController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.jobSeekerList=${jobSeekerJsonArray};

    });
</script>
```

## This is my model (with jsp code)

```
<select id="skills" name="skills" class="form-control2" ng-model="drpSkill">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Skills</option>
    <c:forEach items="${skillVo}" var="skills">
           <option value="${skills.skill}">${skills.skill}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: It is working as intended. Please read filter doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: The problem is that your structure with id=3, contains `"jobSeekerSkillVo" : [ ]` that is an empty array but the filter you applied is `filter:{jobSeekerSkillVo:{skill:drpSkill}`. Clearly, you want only those objects that contains a `jobSeekerSkillVo` array that must contain `skill: something`.

Comment: tq that's the problem

Comment: @Gaurav But how to avoid filtering when page loads first time??.In Above  code filters are applying at time of page loading that's the first reason ,second is  skill:[] is empty.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, instead load your data first.

Comment: If that's not a possibility then you have to apply the filter programmatically at the right time. for more info on how to apply filter programmatically read this -> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives

Comment: Ya know its working fine I applied custom filters and i am calling those filters based on the events